# Adding a comment in the txt version of a png

Tags: file, filesystems, steganography

I am creating this "cicada 3301" style ARG where I want people to take a .png file and change it to a .txt file and open it in an editor and then from there get some information. I once played an ARG myself where I saw this done with the information lying in the bottom of all that jumble text preceded by //andthensometext. I have tried just inserting some text behind double slashes, and then changing it back to .png, however that doesn't work. If anyone knows whether or not this is possible please let me know